# Timer event handler keeps getting called?

Tags: c#, wpf, timer

I seem to have a thread issue I think, I have written a timer to return to the main screen if its on any other screen for 5 seconds. This code works fine the first time the `ResetScreen()` is called, but after it returns to the main screen itself, I can't navigate to any other screen as it keeps returning to the Timer event handler.

I also tested this without the `this.Dispatcher.Invoke` and replaced it with a message box, and it just constant pops up about every second.

```
private void ResetScreen()
{
    if (!mainScreen)
    {
        myTimer = new System.Timers.Timer();
        myTimer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(OnTimedEvent);
        myTimer.Interval = 5000;
        myTimer.Start();
    }
}

private void OnTimedEvent(object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
    myTimer.Stop();
    this.Dispatcher.Invoke((Action)(() =>
    {
        // show main screen
    }));    
}
```

Edit:
I think its just a timer issue in general. Just can't seem to stop the timer.

Comment: how do you call ResetScreen and where myTimer lives?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When using `System.Timers.Timer()` you need to explicitly set the [`AutoReset`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer.autoreset.aspx) property to `false`:

```
myTimer = new System.Timers.Timer();
myTimer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(OnTimedEvent);
myTimer.Interval = 5000;
myTimer.AutoReset = false;
myTimer.Start();
```

Check out the documentation and examples on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer.autoreset.aspx).

Comment: +1! While this can be true, I have a feeling that it is the `ResetScreen` which is getting called too often

Comment: Both correct - I'll just step through my code logic again. Thanks.